# Jasper Report - Include Blank Page after the details section

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I enter a blank page after the ending of details section in a jasper report by using iReport 1.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the palette of iReport there are an Element **Break** :

[image: bread page]

You can drag and drop this to make a blank page.

Or you can add this to your file :

```
<break>
    <reportElement x="0" y="6" 
                   width="100" height="1" 
                   uuid="5c729e99-77f6-4f3d-8c7c-15453db7526f"/>
</break>
```

Or this :

```
<break>
<reportElement x="0" y="1"
               width="842" height="0" key="element-1"/>
</break>
```

Comment: I am using IReport 1.3.3 and it doesn't have a palette object like this hence could you please tell me what kind of tag can be used for it ?